# Unir 2 ficheros en array de bytes en uno

Tags: c#, array, .net

Tengo un método que recibe como parametros 2 ficheros en formato array de bytes y su función es unirlos en un solo array. El problema es que cuando intento abrir el fichero resultante la aplicación me dice que el fichero esta corrupto. El formato de los ficheros es word y el resultado también.

Este es el código que tengo ahora mismo:

```
public static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, ret, 0, first.Length);
    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, ret, first.Length, second.Length);
    return ret;
}
```

He buscado la manera de insertar un salto de página entre ambas copias de bloques pero no he encontrado como.

Utilizando la librería interop de word ya lo tengo solucionado, pero lo que estoy intentando evitar es la dependencia de dicha librería por cuestiones de alojamiento del webservices.

**El motivo de esta pregunta era que el fichero word obtenido en el código de arriba no era legible desde la la aplicación de office y pedía ayuda para evitar el uso de las COM**

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No es posible lo que intentas. No se pueden unir dos ficheros de word simplemente concatenando su contenido. Tendrías que abrir ambos ficheros usando interop o alguna librería de manejo de word para poder unirles.

Comment: Otra opción que puedes usar probablemente,si estás seguro de que los archivos en word están en formato openxml, es usar el [OpenXml SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/bb448854.aspx)

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apunte @Pikoh, optaré entonces por el método interop que ya tengo codificado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para unir documentos `word` tienes que usar una libreria, no se puede realizar a nivel de byte array

Podrias usar `itext` la cual se puede agregar desde nuget

[itext7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/itext7/)

El codigo seria algo como esto

```
    public byte[] Merge(byte[] source1, byte[] source2)
    {
        var m = new MemoryStream();
        using (PdfDocument pdfDestination = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(m)))
        {
            PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdfDestination);

            using (PdfDocument pdfSource = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(source1))))
            {
                int nroPages = pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages();
                merger.Merge(pdfSource, 1, nroPages);
            }

            using (PdfDocument pdfSource = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(source2))))
            {
                int nroPages = pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages();
                merger.Merge(pdfSource, 1, nroPages);
            }
        }

        return m.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Leandro, no se me ocurrió usar esta librería, hace tiempo trabajé con ella y resultó muy útil.